# How to access REST APIs as guest in Magento 2.1.x

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api

I am building a mobile application for a Magento instance. I can use [Token Based Authentication](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html) to make the API calls. However I want to enable guest access in my app. The users should be able to browse the categories and products and add to card without signing in, and only need to sign in when they are checking out. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you able to manage guest user browsing ?

Comment: Did the answer below help you? Anything to report?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the `anonymous` resource for your api method, like:

```
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/path/to/method" method="POST">
        <service class="Vendor\Module\Api\OwnInterface" method="methodName"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous" />
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Because:

> Use the token in a Web API request
>
> Any web API call that accesses a resource **that requires a permission
>   level higher than anonymous** must contain the authentication token in
>   the header To do this, specify a HTTP header in the following format:
>
> Authorization: Bearer

Source: [Token-based authentication](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html)

You can find example here: `magento/module-quote/etc/webapi.xml`